# Azure Search SKD "startswith"

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am using the Azure Search SDK.

One of my fields is a urlpath field, for example "/parentlevel/sublevel/child"

I have the need to do a search and filter on all pages that are at the sublevel or lower.

Somehow I need to do a search that returns records that have a urlpath that startswith "/parentlevel/sublevel/*" If this isn't in the urlpath the record would be excluded from the search.

How can I do this using the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you add [QueryType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters.querytype?view=azure-dotnet) = Full to the SearchParameters, are you able to do the search as you specify (where you would add * at the end of the path)?

Comment: Would this be in the search then? urlpath:/parentlevel/sublevel/child*